# Generate a subset of possible permutations

Tags: python, list, permutation

Lets say I have two lists of lists and I wand to build various permutations from it. Look at these two lists:

```
l1 = [[0, 8], [4], [6, 7], [1], [3], [5], [2]]
l2 = [[4, 8], [0], [6, 7], [3], [1], [5], [2]]
```

The two lists represent mappings, that I already have. So I know some parts of my permutation but not all of them. As I see it, there are only four permutations possible:

```
(4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 5, 6, 7, 8)
(8, 3, 2, 1, 0, 5, 7, 6, 4)
(4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 5, 7, 6, 8)
(8, 3, 2, 1, 0, 5, 6, 7, 4)
```

After thinking about it I have the following idea. I would generate all four possibilities of `l1` (being a tuple in the end) make `l2` into a tuple, do a dictionary zip, order that dictionary and convert these four dicts into a list of tuples. Sound reasonable?
I have a hard time generating the four tuples. This is what I have so far.

```
l1 = [[0, 8], [4], [6, 7], [1], [3], [5], [2]]
l2 = [[4, 8], [0], [6, 7], [3], [1], [5], [2]]

out = [()]
def get_permutations(lst):
    for i in lst:
        for perms in permutations(i):
            out[0] = out[0] + perms
    return out

print(get_permutations(l1))
```

Which prints `[(0, 8, 8, 0, 4, 6, 7, 7, 6, 1, 3, 5, 2)]`
How do I generate another tuple when I get to an entry in my list where more than one permutation of that list entry is possible?

I also know that `print(list(itertools.product(*l1)))` does almost what I want but not quite. It yields `[(0, 4, 6, 1, 3, 5, 2), (0, 4, 7, 1, 3, 5, 2), (8, 4, 6, 1, 3, 5, 2), (8, 4, 7, 1, 3, 5, 2)]`. Maybe there is a way to modify that.

It is not a homework question.
To provide context: I am building a program to test graph isomorphism. The lists are the color classes of the nodes. With these color classes I want to limit all possible permutations of a graph to just a few to make the brute-force quicker.

Comment: This sounds like a homework question

Comment: Provide what you have done so far

Comment: This wikipedia article will certainly help the mathematical standpoint!
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_permutation

Comment: I provided an idea and clarified my problem. This is no homework question.

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at itertools. 
https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations